# SQL Server 2014 - How to remove Null Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that holds data about class entries for a certain journal. I'm trying to separate the results by week so I get a count of those entries per week. But when I group by day, I get null values too. I want to omit records with Null Values. How do I do that?

**I wrote the following code:**

```
SELECT Year(JournalDate) AS YY
      ,Month(JournalDate) AS MM
      ,FromClass
      ,ToClass
      ,(SELECT Count(JournalID) 
        WHERE Day(JournalDate) >= 1 AND Day(JournalDate)=7) AS CountWeek1
      ,(SELECT Count(JournalID) 
        WHERE Day(JournalDate) >= 8 AND Day(JournalDate)=14) AS CountWeek2
      ,(SELECT Count(JournalID) 
        WHERE Day(JournalDate) >= 15 AND Day(JournalDate)=21) AS CountWeek3
      ,(SELECT Count(JournalID) 
        WHERE Day(JournalDate) >= 22 AND Day(JournalDate)=28) AS CountWeek4
      ,(SELECT Count(JournalID) 
        WHERE Day(JournalDate) >= 29 AND Day(JournalDate)=31) AS CountWeek5


  FROM [tblJournal]

  WHERE [JournalDate] >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND FromClass <> ToClass
    --AND CountWeek1 IS NOT Null

  GROUP BY Year(JournalDate), Month(JournalDate), Day( JournalDate), FromClass, ToClass

  ORDER BY YY, MM, FromClass, ToClass
```

**But I get Null values too. I want to remove Null Values.**

```
YY  MM  FrClass ToClass CntWk1  CntWk2  CntWk3  CntWk4  CntWk5
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    20      NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   12      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    29      NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2016    9   1   2   NULL    NULL    NULL    25      NULL
```

How do I omit the records with NULL values?

**EDIT:**
So I would actually like my results to look like this:

```
YY  MM  FrmCls  ToClsWk1    Wk2 Wk3 Wk4 Wk5
2016    9   1   2   12  20  29  25  0
2016    9   1   3   2   1   6   0   0
2016    9   1   4   0   1   2   0   0
2016    9   2   1   0   3   0   2   0
2016    9   2   3   74  46  84  54  0
2016    9   2   4   0   0   8   5   0
2016    9   3   2   0   813 0   0   0
```

Comment: null values to blank?

Comment: or don't include all rows with NULL from Cntwk1 - wk5?

Comment: Question: Do you want one row, with values in all but the last column?  Or do you want four rows (one row for each row that has at least one non-null column)?

Comment: or merging all records to no nulls

Comment: YES. Don't include rows with Null values.

Comment: YES. One row with values in each column.

Comment: you can use max

Comment: How would I use Max in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your data above and insert into a temp table. After that you can query on your result by suming data by year, month, etc. like this:

```
SELECT YY, MM, FrClass,ToClass,SUM(cntwk1),SUM(cntwk2),SUM(cntwk3),SUM(cntwk4),SUM(cntwk5)
FROM #data
GROUP BY YY, MM, FrClass,ToClass
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. How would I use that statement in my code?

Comment: @user1777929 after group by statement.

Comment: That wouldn't quite work because it would only give me records where the 4thw eek has values. All other columns would be null.

Comment: @user1777929 I got it after seeing your edit and what result you want. Refere to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. This code worked. I also added a condition as per @Kostya  where Week1+Week2+Week3+Week4+Week5 <> 0. Worked great! Thank you to BOTH of you.

Answer (score 1):

how about this

```
select * from 
(
SELECT Year(JournalDate) AS YY
      ,Month(JournalDate) AS MM
      ,FromClass
      ,ToClass
      ,isnull((SELECT Count(JournalID) 
        WHERE Day(JournalDate) >= 1 AND Day(JournalDate)=7),0) AS CountWeek1
      ,isnull((SELECT Count(JournalID) 
        WHERE Day(JournalDate) >= 8 AND Day(JournalDate)=14),0) AS CountWeek2
      ,isnull((SELECT Count(JournalID) 
        WHERE Day(JournalDate) >= 15 AND Day(JournalDate)=21),0) AS CountWeek3
      ,isnull((SELECT Count(JournalID) 
        WHERE Day(JournalDate) >= 22 AND Day(JournalDate)=28),0) AS CountWeek4
      ,isnull((SELECT Count(JournalID) 
        WHERE Day(JournalDate) >= 29 AND Day(JournalDate)=31),0) AS CountWeek5


  FROM [tblJournal]

  WHERE [JournalDate] >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND FromClass <> ToClass

  GROUP BY Year(JournalDate), Month(JournalDate), Day( JournalDate), FromClass, ToClass
  ) x 
  where CountWeek1 +CountWeek2+CountWeek3+CountWeek4+CountWeek5 <> 0 

  ORDER BY YY, MM, FromClass, ToClass
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. That worked. However, is there a way to group them further?  Eg; currently, I get  a number in 1 column and the other columns are 0. Then another row with one column that has a number which was earlier 0 in the previous row (for that same group)